# 'Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:7058' when running selenium/capybara test in parallel mode(using 8 threads)

Tags: multithreading, firefox, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, capybara

We ran cukes in parallel mode using 8 threads on Jenkins but most of cukes were failed due to following error.

Error: (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7058) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
./features/support/hooks.rb:3:in `Before'

**Parameters**:

```
OS: Linux
Selenium : gem selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53.4'
Capybara: gem 'capybara', '>= 2.10.0'
Browser: Firefox version 45.5.0
```

**hooks.rb**

```
1.Before do |scenario|
2.Capybara.reset_sessions!
3.  page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
4.  page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
5.end
```

**env.rb**

```
browser=ENV['BROWSER'] || 'ff'
case browser
  when 'ff', 'firefox'
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
      Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=("/usr/bin/firefox") if REGISTRY[:local_path_for_selenium]
      profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
      profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false
      profile.secure_ssl = false
      profile['browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait'] = 100
      profile['browser.manage.timeouts.script_timeout'] = 100
      profile['browser.manage.timeouts.read_timeout'] = 500
      profile['browser.manage.timeouts.page_load'] = 120
      profile["browser.download.folderList"] = 2
      profile['browser.download.dir'] = "#{Rails.root}/downloads"
      profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/xlsx"
      profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile'] = "application/xlsx"
      http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
      http_client.timeout = 410
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile, :http_client => http_client)
    end
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

Regards,
Ajay

Any proposition will be welcome
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?